# TypeError: 'Undefined' object is not iterable?

Tags: javascript, python, odoo, cherrypy, mako

The following is the mako template I have created

```
<%inherit file="/openerp/controllers/templates/base_dispatch.mako"/>
<%def name="header()">
    <title>${_("Otp")}</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">alert("OTP PAGE");</script>
</%def>
<%def name="content()">
    <table width="100%">
        <tr><%include file="header.mako"/></tr>
    </table>
    </br>
    <table class="view" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="padding-top: 10px; border:none;" align="center">
        <tr>
            <td style="padding:35px 10px 5px 35px; width="450"  align="center">
                <form action="${py.url(target)}" method="post" name="otpform" id="otpform" style="padding-bottom: 5px; min-width: 100px;">
                    % for key, value in origArgs.items():
                        <input type="hidden" name="${key}" value="${value}"/>
                    % endfor
                   <input name="otp_action" value="otp" type="hidden"/>
                   <fieldset class="box" style="width:300px">
                        <legend style="padding: 4px;">
                            <img src="/openerp/static/images/stock/stock_person.png" alt=""/>
                        </legend>
                        <div class="box2" style="padding: 5px 5px 20px 5px">
                            <b>Please enter SMS code</b>
                            <table width="" cellspacing="2px" cellpadding="0" style="border:none;">

                                <tr>
                                    <td class="label"><label for="otp">${_("Otp:")}</label></td>
                                    <td style="padding: 3px;"><input type="text" id="otp" name="otp" class="db_user_pass" value="${otp}" autofocus="true"/></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td class="db_login_buttons">
                                        <button type="submit" class="static_boxes">${_("Otp")}</button>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </fieldset>
                </form>

            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <%include file="footer.mako"/>
</%def>
```

And the python file for the template is

```
import re
from openobject.controllers import BaseController
import cherrypy
from openerp.utils import rpc
from mako.lookup import TemplateLookup
from mako.template import Template
from openobject import tools
import openobject
from openobject.tools import expose, url, redirect, validate, error_handler
import formencode
import base64
import time

class OTP(BaseController):

    _cp_path = "/openerp/otp"
    msg = {
           }

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(OTP, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self._msg = {}

    @expose()
    def index(self, *args, **kw):
        print '>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>INDEX<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<'
        self.msg = {}
        target='/'
        url='socket://localhost:8070'
        action='otp'
        info=''
        info = None
        message=''
        origArgs=self.get_orig_args(kw)
        self.otp_check(target, action, message, origArgs)

    @expose(template="/openerp/controllers/templates/otp.mako")
    def otp_check(self, target, action=None, message=None, origArgs={}):
        print '>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>otp_check<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<'
        target='/'
        url='socket://localhost:8070'
        action='otp'
        info=''
        info = None
        return dict(target=target, url=url, action=action, message=message, origArgs=origArgs, info=info)

    def get_orig_args(self,kw):
        if not kw.get('otp_action'):
            return kw

        new_kw = kw.copy()
        clear_login_fields(new_kw)
        return new_kw

# vim:expandtab:smartindent:tabstop=4:softtabstop=4:shiftwidth=4:
```

But on running it I am getting the following error in browser.

```
500 Internal Server Error

The server encountered an unexpected condition which prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/cherrypy/_cprequest.py", line 606, in respond
    cherrypy.response.body = self.handler()
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/cherrypy/_cpdispatch.py", line 25, in __call__
    return self.callable(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "/home/zbeanz/workspace/Sms_authentication/openerp-web-6.0.4/openobject/tools/_expose.py", line 182, in func_wrapper
    res = func(*args, **kw)
  File "/home/zbeanz/workspace/Sms_authentication/openerp-web-6.0.4/openobject/controllers/_root.py", line 90, in default
    return request.handler()
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/cherrypy/_cpdispatch.py", line 25, in __call__
    return self.callable(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "/home/zbeanz/workspace/Sms_authentication/openerp-web-6.0.4/openobject/tools/_expose.py", line 182, in func_wrapper
    res = func(*args, **kw)
  File "/home/zbeanz/workspace/Sms_authentication/openerp-web-6.0.4/addons/openerp/controllers/otp.py", line 83, in index
    self.otp_check(target, action, message, origArgs)
  File "/home/zbeanz/workspace/Sms_authentication/openerp-web-6.0.4/openobject/tools/_expose.py", line 222, in func_wrapper
    return render_template(_template, res).encode("utf-8")
  File "/home/zbeanz/workspace/Sms_authentication/openerp-web-6.0.4/openobject/tools/_expose.py", line 141, in render_template
    return utils.NoEscape(template.render_unicode(**kw))
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/mako/template.py", line 138, in render_unicode
    return runtime._render(self, self.callable_, args, data, as_unicode=True)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/mako/runtime.py", line 364, in _render
    _render_context(template, callable_, context, *args, **_kwargs_for_callable(callable_, data))
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/mako/runtime.py", line 381, in _render_context
    _exec_template(inherit, lclcontext, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/mako/runtime.py", line 414, in _exec_template
    callable_(context, *args, **kwargs)
  File "_openobject_controllers_templates_base_mako", line 61, in render_body
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/mako/runtime.py", line 255, in <lambda>
    return lambda *args, **kwargs:callable_(self.context, *args, **kwargs)
  File "_openerp_controllers_templates_otp_mako", line 89, in render_content
TypeError: 'Undefined' object is not iterable
```

What is causing this error ?

Comment: Can you provide the url you are using to reach index?

Answer (score 3):

The error description is very clear.

```
'Undefined' object is not iterable
```

i.e you have a list object and try to iterate in your mako file. But in runtime the object is not assigned with value. so the object is undefined. In your case you iterate only one variable

```
% for key, value in origArgs.items():
     <input type="hidden" name="${key}" value="${value}"/>
% endfor
```

check if variable **origArgs** has got values while running. It's good to handle this kind of exceptions like below

```
%if origArgs:
    % for key, value in origArgs.items():
       <input type="hidden" name="${key}" value="${value}"/>
    % endfor
 %endif
```

If that's not the one causing error, then check for the iterables in file "/openerp/controllers/templates/base_dispatch.mako". You must be able to get it. If still no luck, leave a comment below. Cheers!!